# jQuery UI Autocomplete with fixed header

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I'm working on a project that requires a "product search" which will display a grid with product names and prices.

I'm using jQuery UI with the Autocomplete widget to achieve this, and I pretty much have it all working as I want.

To display the "grid" I'm using floating divs per row acting as fake table cells, by overiding the _renderItem function:

```
$('#search').autocomplete().data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item){
    var line_item = '';
    line_item += "<a><div class='search_row'>";
    line_item += "<div class='sku'>"+item.sku+"</div>";
    line_item += "<div class='product_name'>"+item.label+"</div>";
    line_item += "<div class='product_price'>ET:"+item.price+"</div>";
    line_item += "</div></a>";

    return $("<li>")
    .append(line_item)
    .appendTo(ul);
};
```

The grid is limited to 400px height with vertical scrolling.

My only problem now is that I'd like some fixed headers at the top, that don't scroll.

I tried using something similar to:

```
$('#search').autocomplete().data("ui-autocomplete")._renderMenu = function(ul, items){
    var self = this;
    $.each(items, function(index, item){
        if(index == 0){
            ul.append('<li><div style="position:fixed; background-color:blue;">TEST HEADERS</div></li>');
        }

        self._renderItem(ul, item);
    });
};
```

But then I get into another set of layout problems.

Is there another ("more native") way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: by more native to you mean an '<lh>' (list header tag)?

Comment: You could add a div outside of the list with position: fixed?

Comment: I guess what I mean is "cleaner way" instead of having to hack one of the internal functions of the widget.

Comment: I am assuming you have done this when you said you limited the height to 400px: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#maxheight  Also, could you paste the html that is surrounding your autocomplete input?