# Jquery UI autocomplete header

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a jQuery UI autocomplete (with custom styling) where I added an header.

You can see it at work here:

http://jsfiddle.net/fbonomi/wJWGV/

the header is added like this:

```
function cComboboxOpen( event) 
{
    var s='.... header .....';
    $("ul.ui-autocomplete[style*='block']").prepend(s); 
}
```

it works, and it keeps the column-like form I need (the real data will also be in columns)

BUT, I would like to have the header NOT scrolling away when you have a long, scrollable list (e.g if you type "a" in the list)

I have seen another very similar question here: 
[jQuery UI Autocomplete with fixed header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798061/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-fixed-header)
But it hasn't been answered, and in its current form it does not work properly (the header is "fixed" even when one scrolls the page, for example)

How can I avoid the header to scroll away?

Comment: I have the same question.  Did you ever find a solution @kanaka?